# php mail function not working in new server

Tags: php, server, smtp, port, phpmailer

**Background**

My [visitmeemure.com](http://www.visitmeemure.com/) was hosted in [ipage server](https://www.ipage.com/) and everything worked fine.

Then I have moved my site to [smartersap.net](https://www.smarterasp.net/) and now I'm receiving below error when someone submit the contact us form.

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in H:\root\home\cmadurawala-001\www\aaaa\contact.php on line 77

Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in H:\root\home\cmadurawala-001\www\www\aaaa\contact.php on line 79
```

So I have contacted the server admins and they said that the **don't support php mail function** and I have to  **apply smtp authentication in application**.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this. I am currently using `php mail` function in contact page of my site.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried PHP Mailer Library?

Comment: The primary reason that they don't allow mail() is due to its low level security abs functionality in comparison to other advanced options. Please try https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @Alpha do you mean php mail function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library called PHPMailer. You could use it instead of the native mail() function. This is how the code looks like with PHPMailer

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// here you create the mail object
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

I suggest using composer to install the library and its dependencies.
But, since your app is already in the server, you can just download if from GitHub and put it manually there

More information:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer